# How do i take a link from a user to use as button link?

Tags: javascript, html, button, href

Im working on a project which requires me to take a link(image url for eg) from the user and use it as address for a button which runs a code to carry out some process on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var 
    SiteURL = '';

SiteURL = prompt('What is the URL of the image?');


</script>                       
<a href='linkofuser' class="mybuttonclassforprocess"></a>
```

for some reason, this method isn't working and instead of link desired, it shows "linkofuser" as shown in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add

```
document.getElementById("a").href=SiteURL;
```

look here:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ItayB/m4HPD/)

Comment: you didn't assigned the value returned from prompt to the href. Hope that's help

Comment: it worked on fiddle somehow, but im still not able to replace the href="linkofuser" with the link the user entered. it takes me to a page which doesnt exist due to this.

Comment: try to see what you get (in chrome developer tool console) when you write: document.getElementById("a"). Did you add the id="a" to the <a> element?

Comment: and..? what did you get in console? you get the <a> element? or undefined?

Comment: BTW - You should put the script section after the HTML section and not before.

Comment: Does it work now? (after changing the order of javascript & html)?

Comment: i get an error. its as though the link is not getting saved or used

Comment: it worked now!! javascript,html were out of order..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

DuckVader,

A further explanation of the key components you are missing which ItayB is helping you with:

1) You must **create a unique reference to your document element**. In your case `<a></a>` tag.

```
<a href="" id="a">YOur LInk <a/>
```

2) **A method/function in Javascript to find this element in your document**:

"document.getElementById("[id-name]"); // in your case substitue "a" for parameter [id-name]

**Note**: function name is case sensitive

3) Once you've obtained the reference you must then **modify the attribute**:

Note: in your case it is the **"href**" field after you obtain input string from user:

**document.getElementById("a").href = SiteURL;**

Scott